# PolygonToCenterline: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'topographic'

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, error, esri-production-mapping

I want to create a centerline from a river polygon using PolygonToCenterline. It works when I use the tool in ArcGIS, but when I run it from the script I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'topographic'`

I need to be able to run it from the script. I use ArcGIS Pro 2.2.0 with an advanced license. I think I did it exactly as in the description. Any ideas what I could try? I added the code below:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
# Check out Production Mapping License
arcpy.CheckOutExtension ('foundation')
# Define variables
river_polygon = r'C:\zhaw\masterarbeit\data\diego\typical_rivers.gdb\birs_2011'
out_gdb = r'C:\zhaw\masterarbeit\data\diego\typical_rivers.gdb\centerline'
# Execute Polygon To Centerline
arcpy.topographic.PolygonToCenterline(river_polygon, out_folder)
```

Comment: What version of Python / arcpy are you using, and are you running directly from command line or through an IDE? I don't see this tool in ArcGIS 10.5 help, so I suspect it's accessing arcpy for an earlier version instead of Pro.  Here's a link for the various ways to start Python for ArcGIS Pro: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/installing-python-for-arcgis-pro.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I used Python 2.7.13 running it through Wing IDE. When I ran it using Python 3.6.5 it worked just fine.

Comment: Great! I'll add this as an official answer. Please take a moment to accept it when you have a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm what version of Python / arcpy is being used. I don't see this tool in ArcGIS 10.5 help, so it's probably accessing arcpy for an earlier version instead of Pro. Here's a link for the various ways to start Python for ArcGIS Pro: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/installing-python-for-arcgis-pro.htm

For example, you can start from a command line by using `"%PROGRAMFILES%\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts\propy"`

If working within an IDE, check to see which version of Python is being used. It should be 3.x for Pro, not 2.x.